# Understanding mathematical explanation for Chudakov Effect

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, color-charge

I'm trying to better understand some properties of QCD and currently I'm looking into understanding color coherence. I've got the book *"Elementary Particle Physics: Foundations of the Standard Model, Volume 2"* which is also available on [google books](https://books.google.de/books?id=QYlX6AL4CtwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

In the chapter on color coherence ([Section 10.2](https://books.google.de/books?id=QYlX6AL4CtwC&lpg=PA1&pg=PT444#v=onepage&q&f=false)), the QCD is related to the QED Chudakov Effect. I'm trying to understand the mathematical explanation presented in that section, however, I fail to understand what is done, especially since the derivation is full of (hidden) approximations. There's two steps which I can't figure out. Furthermore, I've got some questions regarding the implication. I've linked the full book above and I'll walk you through the derivation as a I understand it. I've highlighted my specific questions as quotes. Hopefully a seasoned QCD calculator can shed some light :-).

The effect happens in the process of $\gamma \to e^+e^- \to e^+e^-\gamma$ which followed the diagram below:

[image: chudakov effect illustration]

The electron/positron are labelled as $i$ / $j$. Derivation starts by saying that the electron produced at the splitting vertex of the initial photon is virtual and de-excites by emitting the final-state photon with momentum $k$. Afterwards, the real electron has momentum $p$. Two approximations are listed:

1. $|k| \ll |p|$, and
2. $\theta_i = \cos^{-1}(k \cdot p / |k \cdot p |) \to 0$ (small angle approximation?)

---

**1. Energy Imbalance**

Now, the energy difference (energy imbalance?) between the virtual and real final state is

$\Delta E = \sqrt{p^2 + m^2} + |k| - \sqrt{(p+k)^2 + m^2} \sim |k|\theta_i^2$

I understand the first part of the equation, however I fail to see how to obtain the approximation. I either end up with many more terms or a $\Delta E = 0$ depending on how strongly I interpret the two approximations listed beforehand.

> What are the steps to obtain the approximated energy difference?

Using the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, this energy difference is related to the *lifetime* of the virtual electron:

$\Delta t \sim \frac1{\Delta E} \approx \frac1{|k|\theta_i^2} = \frac1{|k_T|\theta_i} \approx \frac{\lambda_T}{\theta_i}$

where $\lambda_T$ is the wave length of the photon transverse to the electron (?).

**2. Separation of $e^+e^-$**

According to the book, the $e^+e^-$ separate by $\Delta d$ during the timespan $\Delta t$:

$\Delta d = \Delta t \cdot \theta_{ij} = \lambda_T \frac{\theta_{ij}}{\theta_i}$

how does this relation work? Presumably the small angle approximation is used somehow, but I fail to understand how the $e^+e^-$ separate by one unit of $\theta_{ij}$ per unit of time.

> How is this formula for the separation $\Delta d$ derived?

The argument for the Chudakov effect is then that $\Delta d$ must be larger than $\lambda_T$ since the emitted photon can not distinguish the two otherwise which would imply that it would radiate off a electrically neutral object. Therefore, $\theta_i < \theta_{ij}$.

> - How does this change when $\theta_{ij}$ is not small (i.e. the $e^+e^-$ pair has appreciable opening angle)? The small angle approximation is used but is this just to enable a quick calculation? I guess as the opening angle gets larger, the distance $\Delta d$ grows much more quickly, so this might enable more large-angle photon radiation (which is consistent with the result predicted above). However, can this actually be inferred from the calculation presented here?
> - As I understand it, this scales with the energy of the photon, i.e. a slightly harder photon may be emitted at a slightly larger angle $\theta_i$. In other words, for two photons $a$ and $b$ with $|k|^{(a)} > |k|^{(b)}$ we can expect that the maximum realistic $\theta_i$ is also following $\theta_i^{(a)} > \theta_i^{(b)}$. Is this correct?
> - Does this calculation say anything about whether emitting the photon *between* the $e^+e^-$ is more likely than outside of their cone?

Thanks for your help!